# Julia: Proper use of isreadable() to prevent "unable to read directory" error

Tags: julia

I am using Julia to run through my filesystem and keep running into an "unable to read directory" error. However, isreadable() always returns true on the particular directory that is giving me problems. Is this the expected behavior? Am I using it incorrectly?

```
julia> isdir(dir)
true

julia> isreadable(dir)
true

julia> readdir(dir)
ERROR: unable to read directory /this/is/a/sample/dir/: Permission denied
 in readdir at ./file.jl:155
```

I am running Julia 0.3.0-prerelease+3921 in Ubuntu 12.04.

Thank you

Comment: In *can* use a try-catch block to get around this, but it is not preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A directory needs to be readable by the owner of the process attempting the read of the directory for **readdir** to succeed.  It turns out that **[isreadable](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/stat.jl#L76)** is defined in the following way

```
isreadable(st::StatStruct) = (st.mode & 0o444) > 0
```

Which means as long as the directory is readable by any user, **isreadable** will return true.

So if the directory is readable only by its owner but the owner of the process is different than the owner of the file, **isreadable** will return true, but **readdir** will fail.

To fix this problem, one must potentially compare owner, group, and other permissions as applicable. The function **stat** can be used to determine owner, group, other permissions, but getting info about the current user seems currently limited.  But, you can always do some shell processing.  For example the following will get the uid of the current process and compare it to the owner of the file.

```
uid = int(split(readall(`ps nup $(getpid())`),'\n')[2][1:8])
x=stat(dir)
same_user = uid == x.uid
```

likewise here's a convenience function to check for readability by owner

```
readable_by_owner = operm(x) & 4
```